# CentOS Server - Available disk space constantly drops

Tags: linux, centos, log-files, disk-space-utilization

The result of the df command :

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2      864000688 809338092  10773908  99% /
tmpfs           32965940         0  32965940   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1         198337     87394    100703  47% /boot
```

the Result of the df command a few seconds later :

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2      864000688 809400076  10711924  99% /
tmpfs           32965940         0  32965940   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1         198337     87394    100703  47% /boot
```

I'm loosing disk space on my server with an incredible speed. And everytime the available space reaches 0 octect, the Mysql service crash.

I already have `reboot` the server to clear the `dmesg` logs, I have deleted every big logs files (error logs, message logs and named.run logs) and run this request : `sudo /usr/sbin/lsof | grep deleted`.

However the space I freed was eaten in a day time.

So I have run requests like :

```
du -hsx * | sort -rh | head -15
```

and this :

```
find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 du | sort -n | tail -10 | cut -f2 | xargs -I{} du -sh {
```

In every directories from my root directory.

But the biggest file I could find was a dump from my database and it's only a 1Gb file :

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1032237681  6 déc.   2013 dump_experta2.sql
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  389789251  6 déc.   2013 dump_experta.sql
```

Can you explain me why the available space seems to be used by some invisible files ? And how may I localize and stop this space disk leak ?

**Edit :** Thanks to HBruijn's tips, I solved my problem, here is what I did step by step if you experience the same issue :

I ran `find / -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -print0 |xargs -0 du -s`

And got this result :

```
1216308 /usr
23356   /lib64
73176   /root
440     /tmp
4       /selinux
4       /command
5574820 /var
4       /media
16      /lost+found
352388  /lib
8       /opt
0       /.autorelabel
4       /service
0       /sys
36500   /www
0       /proc
81785   /boot
7760    /bin
160     /dev
742949400       /home
14572   /sbin
0       /currentsize
0       /.autofsck
2092    /package
4       /srv
4       /mnt
27676   /etc
72944   /test
```

So it seems that the home directory is the biggest one so I repeated the process to find the biggest directory inside home :

```
# find /home -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -print0 |xargs -0 du -s
133952  /home/advisio
16      /home/dovecot
2210824 /home/vpopmail
186500  /home/admin
37152   /home/ginger
511121816       /home/user1
229278612       /home/user2
```

And I repeated the process and saw that the user1 data has grown so I continued searching in user1 directory and found those two heavy directories :

```
281766156       /home/user1/www/log
207269420       /home/user1/www/fichiers
```

The size of the "fichiers" dir is not unusual because it is used to store countless pdf and pictures files. So I look upon the log folder and found this :

```
# ls -l
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vroom users 288586156425  2 juil. 15:34 log-sql-error.txt
```

I realised that what you said about my searching method was incredibly right. I manage to miss a 288 Gb log file by searching logs in wrong directories.

**Anyway I have stoped the `httpd` and the `mysqld` services, emptied the error log and here is my df now :**

```
Filesystem     1G-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2           824G  505G      278G  65% /
tmpfs                32G    0G       32G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             1G    1G        1G  47% /boot
```

**For now, I'll use your advices when I'll search heavy files and folders, Thank you !**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: the sequence `find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 du | sort -n` is incredibly recursive and inefficient.
Finding the **largest files**, with `find / -type f -print0 | xargs -0 du | sort -n` is already much better with `find / -type f -printf "%s %p\n" |sort -n` even more efficient.

Often more telling is *where* you lose your disk space and finding the **largest directories** quickly (`du`**`-s`**) instead because many small files also add up (think mail queue, print spool  etc.)

Second: when you ran `find` *"in every directories from my root directory"* you may have overlooked "hidden" files/directories under your root `/` i.e. simple ones starting with a dot `/.<name>`  and less obvious ones such as ones consisting of only a space `/ /` or a TAB character.

Start with:

```
find / -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -print0 |xargs -0 du -s
```

and work your way down from that.

You already looked at deleted files that might still be held open with `lsof`  but you might have processes writing large (temporary) files and it might be interesting and useful to watch `sudo lsof -s | awk '$5 == "REG"' | sort -n -r -k 7,7 | head -n 50`

Comment: you can shorten that without a pipe just using du  `du / -s --max-depth=1`

Comment: My Mac with the BSD version of tools always trips me up, yes indeed the GNU version of `du`  has its own depth limiter!

Comment: yep... yours is more will work everywhere command

Answer (score 0):

In the future, use a tool like [ncdu](http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu) to map your filesystem usage. You would have found the log file issue very easily.